# Elasticsearch fuzzy and match combined

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl

Hi I have below set of docs in my elasticsearch

```
{"id":"1","name" : "Waqar Abdul Ghaffar"}
{"id":"21",name" : "Ayesha Waqar"}
{"id":"31",Abdul Sammad"}
{"id":"41","name":"Samad"}
{"id":"51","Abdul-Sammad"}
{"id":"61","Abdus-Samad"}
{"id":"71","Abdus-Sanad"}
```

Now when I search for `sammad`, my search should return `id=31` or `id=51` in first places(with higher score) and others such as `id=41` ``` id=61``id=71 ``` with lower score (some fuzzy match)

Simillary when i search for `samad`, my search should  return `id=61` or `id=41` in first places(with higher score) and others such as `id=51` ``` id=31``id=71 ``` with a lower score (some fuzzy match)

Also, when i search for `sanad`, my search should return `id=71` in first places(with higher score) and others such as `id=41` `id=31` ``` id=61``id=51 ``` with a lower score (some fuzzy match)

I tried using ngram tokenizer but nothing helped.

Thanks in advance